# keyboard IO broken after reattach to tmux/screen

Tags: r, vim, x11, tmux, gnu-screen

After reattaching a screen or tmux session over ssh, I commonly encounter two issues:

- vim tab completion is broken.  `:e <Tab>` produces `:e ^I` instead of suggesting files.  Same for tags (`:tj`).  Closing and re-opening vim fixes this, but at the cost of losing vim state.
- R cannot produce graphics.  I have X11 forwarding (`ssh -X -Y`) enabled.  Closing and re-opening does not help.

I cannot deliberately reproduce the problem by closing my ssh window and re-attaching.  Problem is usually observed after long periods without network connectivity between reattaching, and usually detaching is abrupt (loss of network connectivity).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Vim tab completion:**

This is an issue with screen/tmux's terminal emulator.  If tabs work in your shell (e.g. bash), that's likely to the shell's credit; it knew to map the control sequence for you while vim did not.  Presumably, you could fix this in vim in a similar manner, but then you'd run into the issue in some other interactive program.

I can't speak to tmux, but for screen, you should look to update your ~/.screenrc.  Mine, copied from the default that ships with Redhat (which I no longer use...), includes this:

```
#xterm understands both im/ic and doesn't have a status line.
#Note: Do not specify im and ic in the real termcap/info file as
#some programs (e.g. vi) will not work anymore.
termcap  xterm hs@:cs=\E[%i%d;%dr:im=\E[4h:ei=\E[4l
terminfo xterm hs@:cs=\E[%i%p1%d;%p2%dr:im=\E[4h:ei=\E[4l
```

Heed that comment, it may indicate your issue.

Another reference to vi, which may or may not have come from Redhat's screenrc, is:

```
# Yet another hack:
# Prepend/append register [/] to the paste if ^a^] is pressed.
# This lets me have autoindent mode in vi.
register [ "\033:se noai\015a"
register ] "\033:se ai\015a"
bind ^] paste [.]
```

Hopefully one or both of these will help, or else I've pointed you in the right direction to research what you need to correct your screen/tmux terminal emulation.  Perhaps the answers to [screen, vimrc, and bashrc](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/screen-vimrc-and-bashrc-435283/) over at LinuxQuestions.org can help further.

---

**X11 Forwarding:**

When you *first* launch screen, the $DISPLAY is inherited.  For example, I take advantage of this on my TV server; I launch screen locally (`DISPLAY=localhost:0`), then when I connect to it over SSH, anything I do regarding X pops up on the TV.  Obviously, this is not at all your use case; I'm just trying to educate you on how it works so you can understand the solution.

If you are reconnecting to a screen/tmux session launched by an old SSH connection, you may luck out and have it connected to the same X display (SSH defaults to localhost:10.0 and then increments each time it finds a collision), but that doesn't sound like it's happening for you. (The "localhost" part is optional, as is the ".0" part.  Those shouldn't matter for your purposes.  `DISPLAY=:10` is the same as `DISPLAY=localhost:10.0`)

*Before* you connect to your screen/tmux session, take a look at your $DISPLAY.

```
$ echo $DISPLAY
localhost:10.0
```

Then, log into screen/tmux and set the $DISPLAY to what you saw before.

```
$ screen -r
$ export DISPLAY=localhost:10.0
```

I don't think either screen or tmux are smart enough to go any farther than this (think of my TV server example; this isn't always desired, and asking screen/tmux to test the $DISPLAY and then act contingent on its availability is a bit much), so you have to do this manually.

(This may be annoying if you're like me and add `screen -r >/dev/null 2>&1` in your ~/.bashrc.  I don't run into this issue because I try to avoid X11 forwarding whenever possible due to its being slow as molasses and of course not surviving SSH disconnections.)

Answer (score 0):

The second problem looks like a DISPLAY variable one. Try
`echo $DISPLAY` when you first login and again when you reattach the session.
if they differ (which is what i suspect), `setenv` or `export` it to the correct value.

As for the first problem try taking a look at your tmux.conf (or the default from your install)
cause they were remapping
`<TAB>` to funny actions in the development versions (like clear-history) so maybe
after the reattach, tmux owns the event and not vim.